# При выводе постов отфильтровать по произвольному полю

Tags: php, wordpress

Есть сайт на WordPress. Как при выводе записей отфильтровать их по произвольному полю `status` (и его значению `publish`)?

```
// Query the posts
$all_blog_posts = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("
  SELECT * FROM " . $table_name . " WHERE post_type = 'community' AND post_status = 'publish' ORDER BY post_date DESC LIMIT %d, %d", $start, $per_page ) );
// At the same time, count the number of queried posts
  $count = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("
  SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM " . $table_name . " WHERE post_type = 'community' AND post_status = 'publish'", array() ) );
// Loop into all the posts
...
```

Пробовала так, но в таком случае ничего не отображается:

```
// Query the posts
$all_blog_posts = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("
  SELECT * FROM " . $table_name . " WHERE post_type = 'community' AND post_status = 'publish' AND meta_key = 'status' AND meta_value = 'publish' ORDER BY post_date DESC LIMIT %d, %d", $start, $per_page ) );
// At the same time, count the number of queried posts
  $count = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("
  SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM " . $table_name . " WHERE post_type = 'community' AND post_status = 'publish' AND meta_key = 'status' AND meta_value = 'publish'", array() ) );
// Loop into all the posts
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вы забыли указать мета таблицу по которой фильтруете, вот так должно работать

```
$all_blog_posts = $wpdb->get_results(
  $wpdb->prepare("
    SELECT c.* 
    FROM {$table_name} AS c
    JOIN {$wpdb->postmeta} AS pm ON c.ID = pm.post_id  
    WHERE 1 = 1 
      AND c.post_type = 'community' 
      AND c.post_status = 'publish'
      AND pm.meta_key = 'status'
      AND pm.meta_value = 'publish' 
      ORDER BY c.post_date DESC 
      LIMIT %d, %d",
   $start,
   $per_page )
);
```

запрос для подсчета количества постов

```
$count = $wpdb->get_var("
    SELECT COUNT(c.ID) 
    FROM {$table_name} AS c
    JOIN {$wpdb->postmeta} AS pm ON c.ID = pm.post_id  
    WHERE 1 = 1 
      AND c.post_type = 'community' 
      AND c.post_status = 'publish'
      AND pm.meta_key = 'status'
      AND pm.meta_value = 'publish'      
");
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Но пропала пагинация. Для второй части кода не могли бы прописать? )

Comment: @АннаМатвеева дополнил ответ, если правильно понял что вы имеете ввиду)